# How do you reference a code commit tag in IAM

Tags: aws-iam

If I add a tag to a codecommit repo with
code commit => the repo => Settings => repository tags => add tags
how do i reference this tag in IAM

I have in the policy document a statment i am trying to use to reference the tag Im not sure what i use in the resource section to refrence a tag I add.

statement {
  sid = "AllowCodeCommitAccess"
  actions = [
    "codecommit:GitPull",
  ]
resources = ["?????????"]
}

Also I haven't actually added the tag yet to codecommit repo as something on aws said it could impact access. I assume that just means If IAM uses it to denny resources but wasn't %100 sure and haven't added it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i needed to allow or the eqivalent StringNotEquals to deny useing the tag
aws:ResourceTag

```
"Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Key_-1": "Value_-1"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm confused your question. It's meant to prevent git pull IAM user for specific repository or something else?

Here is example of how to deny policy for specific repository that can be attached to your IAM users.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "Action" : [
        "codecommit:*"
      ],
      "Resource" : [
        "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:myrepo"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To allow or deny permitions based on tags added to the repos so the tags can then be used to determin the repos diffrent groups of users have what  access